# Whats the best tools for drawing a "system overview" diagram?

Tags: visual-studio, architecture, system, diagram, visio

What tools is best for drawing an overview of a system for a new starter.
I want to show the components and if possible the technologies they use.
Current options include: Visio, Word, EA?, Paint!
Visual Studio isn't an option (too exprensive).

Comment: Careful with that suggestion!  I worked with an... uh... "old school" BA who liked to manually draw charts, scan them, then email.  Change management was a brutal process with that particular individual...

Comment: Visual Studio has a free full version called Express

Comment: I know that this question is pretty old but for people who are still searching for a new tool, take a look at Archimate

Comment: https://buildazure.com/2015/06/09/microsoft-azure-architecture-blueprints-free-visio-symbols/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the exact same issue a short while back and tried all those tools (and others). Here's what I found:

PowerPoint's the best option! You probably already know how to use it and it gets the job done.

If you're looking for some neat diagram elements (e.g. pictures of network components and such) then Visio is also a pretty good option.

Enterprise Architect (EA) is an overkill for the job and unless you're already proficient with it you'll find yourself spending way too much time on figuring out how to get it to do your bidding rather than just drawing the damn overview.

Paint is is too simplistic - you'll be more productive with PowerPoint.

Answer (score 7):

As VS is too expensive, perhaps [Google Draw](http://www.google.com/google-d-s/drawings/) would fit the bill? It's part of Google Docs, which is free. Just sign in with your Google account.

It's got all the normal flow chart symbols, I find it dead easy to use, and it's on line so you can share it with a new starter just by sending them the URL and giving them access to the drawing.

I use it for nearly all my system diagrams now, because it's so easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.bubbl.us/  (fast mindmapping)

http://www.Draw.io/ (online diagrams, incl. UML)

http://www.visual-paradigm.com/ (client program that needs to be installed)

Comment: draw.io seems like a good option.

Answer (score 1):

I have taken to a combination of visio and powerpoint, usually embedding flowcharts into a PP deck.  I've found I get more bang for the buck by maintaining a living architecture diagram in visio and then referencing it in other materials appropriate for their audience.  For example, I might want to reference an arch diagram in both an introductory slideshow as well as detailed API documentation.